# Unzip/gunzip works fine from terminal but gives error when called from another shell

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, zip

I am trying to unzip/gunzip a file from the terminal and it works absolutely fine.

When I put the same in a sh file and call it from terminal it works fine too!

```
 echo "started"
for file in $filepath/*; do
echo "filename ",$file
if [[ $file == *.zip ]]; then
        #unzip -o $path$file -d $path
      unzip $file
      #jar xvf $path$file -d $path
      #tar -xvf {$path$file} -C $path
      #rm $file
elif [[ $file == *.gz ]]; then
        #unzip -o $path$file -d $path
      gunzip $file
      #jar xvf $path$file -d $path
      #tar -xvf {$path$file} -C $path
  else
        echo "file name is not csv or zip ", $file
fi
done
```

But when I call this from another shell script(which is part of inotifywait), it gives the following errors.
For gz

```
gzip: /usr/apps/{somepath}/6206553653146575.csv.gz: unexpected end of file
```

for zip

```
Archive:  /usr/apps/{somepath}/3020393677273733265.csv.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of 
/usr/apps/{somepath}/3020393677273733265.csv.zip or
/usr/apps/{somepath}/3020393677273733265.csv.zip.zip, and cannot find 
/usr/apps/{somepath}/3020393677273733265.csv.zip.ZIP, period.
```

What did I try already:

Changed execution to #!/bin/bash

Tried to add .zip/.gz at the end of the file name.

Thanks for the help. Appreciate that.

Comment: Maybe its a problem withthe shell being used. What happens if you add "#! /bin/bash" as the dfirst line of the script to force it to use the bash interpreter rathere then possibly something else?

Comment: It gives same error even when i add it

Comment: Clutching at straws here but could it be related to selinux? (Does /var/log/audit.log give.any clues / what happens if you do setenforce 0 ?)

Comment: setenforce 0 says command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned `inotifywait`. I **guess** you're trying to extract files as soon as they appear. It looks to me in some cases `unzip` or `gunzip` is run when the file it is told to extract is incomplete yet.

Possible causes:

- You catch wrong events (e.g. `open`, `create` or `modify`) instead of these that would suggest the file is now complete (`moved_to`, `close_write`).
- Your script gets no information about the file that triggered it. The script uses `for` and tries to extract *all* files with suitable names. Even if you properly catch a file when it's complete, the script will *also* try to extract other files (if any), including incomplete ones.

What to improve:

- Catch right events.
- Rebuild the logic so the script knows which file it's supposed to process. Let each file trigger its own instance of the script, so any single instance of the script processes just one file. It may do little (e.g. it may exit because the name of the file is not what you want) but don't let it do too much (process other files).
- Implement some way(s) to confirm the given file is complete. Few ideas:

  - checking if the file is no longer open (`fuser`, `lsof`);
  - checking if the file hasn't grown for several seconds;
  - silently testing the file integrity (`gunzip -t`, `unzip -t`).

Comment: Wow. It was a wonderful explanation and perfect catch of my issue. I changed create to close_write and now everything is good. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Termcap is messing wih you.  I don't run into it too often, I've never bothered to understand exactly why, I just work around it.  Use strace with unzip, then go view the dump.

```
$ ls 
lorem_ipsum_2.zip  lorem_ipsum.zip
$ for z in lorem_ipsum.zip; do strace unzip $z 2>strace.dump; done
```

Go to the stat call, just prior to the file open and you will see the termcap colorization as part of the file name (hence, you won't see it on the console).

```
stat("\[\033\[01;31lorem_ipsum.zip\[\033\[01;31", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1544, ...}) = 0
```

If you just want to work around it, do something like this.

```
$ LS_BU=$LS_COLORS;LS_COLORS=""
$ for z in $(ls *zip); do unzip $z; done
Archive:  lorem_ipsum_2.zip
  inflating: lorem_ipsum_2.txt
Archive:  lorem_ipsum.zip
  inflating: lorem_ipsum.txt
$ LS_COLORS=$LS_BU
```

If you want to solve it, the answer is probably down in here
https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html

Answer (score 0):

solved ....

I'm using intotifywait,

The trick to avoid the error is to add a sleep 5 in the bucle, like this :

/usr/bin/inotifywait -m /your folder -e create |
while read file; do
sleep 5
do something withe the $file
done